# How to don't change a size of the button when adding a new line to the button text and increasing the button size?

Tags: android, xml, button

For example, I have a vertical linear layout with 2 buttons which have `android:layout_weight="1"` inside. The problem is that if I add a new line to the button text using `&#10;` and increase its size, that button becomes bigger than another one. How to make a button to not change its size if the text size was changed?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00ACC1"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button18"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/colorofbuttons"
            android:fontFamily="@font/architects_daughter"
            android:text="Mom"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp"></Button>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button19"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/colorofbuttons"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="@font/architects_daughter"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="My&#10;Name"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button20"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/colorofbuttons"
            android:fontFamily="@font/architects_daughter"
            android:text="Dad"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button21"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/colorofbuttons"
            android:fontFamily="@font/architects_daughter"
            android:text="Girl"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have tried use `android:maxLines="1"` and `android:ellipsize="end"` in your `button`

Comment: Thanks for reply. It didn't work as I wanted. If the text is "my<next line>name", now is showing my ...

Comment: Can you provide the XML code?

Comment: @PhilipDaniel Check my answer below mate !

Comment: @PhilipDaniel can you please share your expected output with question as image or screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your button code **REPLACE**

```
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

With

```
        android:layout_height="0dp"
```

it will work :)

Comment: I tried this before. It make the button smaller instead of bigger. I want it to be the same size as the one above.

Comment: Yes i should be i the scope of button , it will just make two buttons occupy the spaces half and half, no more and no less

Comment: @MohanKumar thank you, I didn't realize at first that I had to set 0dp to both upper and the lower buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this in your XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00ACC1"
    android:weightSum="2"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button

            android:id="@+id/button18"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text="Mom"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button19"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="My&#10;Name"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button20"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text="Dad"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button21"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text="Girl"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```